# Typescript bigint exceeds (non-specified) maximum; `RangeError: Maximum BigInt size exceeded`

Tags: node.js, typescript, cryptojs, bigint

For safe prime `p`, prime `q = (p - 1)/2`, and generator `g = 2`, we have a distinct sequence (`mod p`):

`g^0,g^1,...,g^q-1`

Then the sequence repeats,

`g^q (mod p) = g^0 (mod p)`

**The largest necessary bigint is `g^q-1`, but can't be computed, `npx ts-node Test.ts`:**

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const dh = crypto.createDiffieHellman(1024);
const p = BigInt(`0x${dh.getPrime().toString('hex')}`);
const g = BigInt(`0x${dh.getGenerator().toString('hex')}`);
const q = (p - 1n)/2n;

console.log(g ** 0n % p)
console.log(g ** 1n % p)
console.log(g ** (q-1n) % p)
```

As expect, `1n` and `2n` are output, then:

```
    console.log(g ** (q-1n) % p)
                 ^
RangeError: Maximum BigInt size exceeded
```

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`g ** (q-1n) % p` is too big because the reduction mod `p` is done only at the end and `g ** (q-1n)` is indeed too big for the standard representation as a `BigInt`: it has more hex digits than there are atoms in the universe.

This "intermediate overflow" would not happen if you reduced mod `p` after each multiplication (this does not change the result):

```js
function powermod(base, exp, p) {
  var result = 1n;
  while (exp !== 0n) {
    if (exp % 2n === 1n) result = result * base % p;
    base = base * base % p;
    exp >>= 1n;
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(powermod(g, q-1n, p));
```

(This is not necessarily the fastest way to compute the power, see [taocp](/questions/tagged/taocp), section 4.6.3.)

`powermod` is a ternary operation which cannot be expressed in terms of the binary operations `**` and `%`, unless a Javascript engine is able to recognize an expression like `base ** exp % p` and treat it as ternary. I don't know if such Javascript engines exist. But there are npm packages for "finite fields" that implement this operation.

Comment: Yes, I can see that works; `bigint` operations seem rather redundant if they can't be used as given.

Comment: You still need `BigInt` to accomodate the numbers returned by `dh`.

Comment: Yes, I appreciate that—I agree with you—I'm just perplexed as to why `**` is defined when it can't be used as expected: I want `**` to do it's job—I want to write readable code—I don't want an intuitively unnecessary method call littering my code. (I was expecting too much!)

Comment: You are doing arithmetic over a finite field with `p` elements, whereas `BigInt`'s arithmetic deals with integers, so it cannot serve your needs.

Comment: Actually, "BigInt values represent numeric values which are too large to be represented by the number primitive" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt). BigInt is oversold. I'm not surprised! Performing operations on large numbers is hard. Operator precedence (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) seems incompatible with operations on large numbers—remainder (%) needs to be considered in conjunction with (at least) exponentiation (**) to avoid RangeError.

Comment: I owe you a plus one; I just don't have the reputation to give right now. You've now expanded your answer to explain why BigInt is technically unable to perform such computations and I've now marked as the accepted answer, thanks. I'd still like to know more: Sure, more hex than atoms suffices to answer, but we know computing `g ** (q-1n)` then applying `% p` is inefficient, more efficient computation could have been built in—I'm interested to learn the limitations of BigInt, without understanding those, BigInt feels dangerous, I don't know when failure will emerge.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon an [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75387232/19341862) in an attempt to answer my own question:

`BigInt` is *a best effort* to "represent numeric values which are too large to be represented by the number primitive" and to define "the following operators": `+ * - % **` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt).

Unfortunately, this best effort fails: For instance, large exponents produce numbers which can't be handled.

Such limitations can be overcome, e.g., large exponents modulo some divisor can be computed by other means, without using the exponentiation operator.

Some limitation appears (seemingly) due to operator precedence (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence): Exponentiation (`**`) takes precedence over remainder (`%`), whereas these operations need to be considered in conjunction to avoid error.

Presumably—similarly to `Number`—there exist maximum and minimum numeric values after which `RangeError` will arise.

---

**TL;DR**: `BigInt` is a best effort; computations may produce numbers `BigInt` can't handle and `RangeError` will arise.